# AWS S3 downloads folder indstead opening browser

Tags: jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, war, web-hosting

I'm trying to make my website online with AWS. I've the .war file, which I've compressed and uploaded in my bucket in S3, and made public. I've also deployed the app and followed the tutorials AWS have, but it doesn't work. When I click on the link it downloads the file even though it should open my JSP in the browser. Why?

Comment: How have u deployed the app? What link are u clicking, the war file?

Comment: Yes I've deployed the app. The link I'm clicking is the one I get in the S3 under "Properties"

Comment: Where have you deployed the war? On an ec2 instance?

Comment: S3 is for file sharing, you cannot deploy an war file on s3.. You can have some static HTML pages but it cannot work as a web server to serve dynamic web pages.

Comment: How do I run it then? When I uploaded the html only it gave me illegalargumentexception malfomed for the applet.

Comment: You will need an web container like tomcat or application server to run ur jsps and Java . You need to launch an ec2 instance. You can then SSH into the server and then install tomcat on the instance. You can then deploy ur application.

Comment: Once running you can use route 53 mapping for ur application.

Comment: You can also try aws beanstalk. You will not need to manage the ec2 instance.

Comment: I've tried the aws beanstalk, but every time I upload and deploy the war file it gives me errors that It couldn't launch the WEB-INF

Comment: If you are comfortable with docker, you can try aws ecs.

Comment: The health status, and have got the warning: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Degraded. Application update completed 11 seconds ago and took 86 seconds. Impaired services on all instances.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is file hosting. You've uploaded a java JAR there, which simply stores it (like how dropbox works, if you are more familiar with that).

You need to run a server than understands how to run a JAR. A good example of that is Tomcat; [ElasticBeanstalk supports Tomcat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html), which is easier than running your own server.